# Convert excel A to excel B for a user using python in background

Tags: python

I have wrote some python code using 2 packages;

Xlrd to read in data from a messy audit
and
Xlsx writer to format this into a better presented excel sheet with the most important data only

I would like to know the best direction to go in now where I can present this to someone who won't need python. 
I am getting familiar with django and assuming it is my best option(?) but a nudge in the correct path of reading material or modules needed to learn would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: They would not require python if you are outputting the _important data_ to an excel file, they would only need an excel file viewer like Microsoft Office or LibreOffice to open it once the file is created.

Comment: Its probably the way I worded my question but I meant in a way where they could automatically do the convert, every time they got a new audit, without my input. Maybe them uploading > python code > displaying new data as a webpage, would be better than needing a second excel file.

Comment: And also if their was the possibility of me being able to present it to them without me ever needing to know what's in the new audits it would be a lot better too.

Comment: Sounds like they would have to upload the audit file to a server (could be Django based) and the excel processing could be done at this point. Upon completion of processing, the server could send the user to a _report_ web page which you would have to design to display the *important data*. You could also look into [web reporting packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021252/python-based-web-reporting-tool).